# semantic ui dimmer module not available within meteor

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

I have installed the semantic:ui 1.12.1 package. I can't use semantic's modals. It throws an error;

```
$dimmer.on is not a function
at Object.$.fn.modal.$allModules.each.module.set.clickaway
```

dimmer is true in client/lib/custom.semantic.json.
I tried installing semantic:ui-dimmer 1.12.0, but it didn't help.
Other parts of semantic appear to be working, how do I get semantic-ui modals to work in Meteor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373124/bug-in-meteor-semantic-ui Did you solve this already?

Comment: I added an answer on the other/similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373124/bug-in-meteor-semantic-ui).  The question here doesn't have enough information.  Show some code please.