# Semantic UI Modal only shows up once in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor, semantic-ui

I have got a meteor app which uses the Semantic UI. I am using the semantic:ui-css package for this.

I have got a template called project where I want to show a modal.
There for I created a second template which is the modal like this:

```
<template name="xform">
  <div id="modal" class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">New Project</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui form" id="newProject">
      <div class="one fields">
        <div class="field">
          <legend>Project Details</legend>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Project name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="button small createProject" style="color:white;position:relative;float:right;padding: 0.875rem 1.75rem 0.9375rem 1.75rem;font-size: 0.8125rem;" value="Create">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui button">
      Cancel
    </div>
    <div class="ui button">
      Okay
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then I haved added a event to a button like this to show the modal:

```
Template.projects.events({
  'click .newProject': function(event, template){
    template.$('.ui.modal').modal({
          onDeny    : function(){
            return false;
          }}).modal('show');
  }
});
```

If I click the button for the first time the modal opens like wanted.
I can see that the modal is now not anymore inside the html of my template but at the end of my body.
I can close the modal using the close button but when I now try to open it again it does not open any more.
The modal div is still on the bottom of my body.

I have tried several ways to workaround this problem but none have worked.

Here my complete code: http://i.imgur.com/r9JNrlr

Comment: You've basically answered the question, the semantic ui modal code moves the div to the bottom of the body, so when you call `template.$('.ui.modal')...` you are only 'looking' for `.ui.modal` inside the template - in this case the 'projects' template. The easiest although not necessarily correct way would be to just use the global jQuery object `$('.ui.modal')`. By not necessarily correct I mean you should probably reference it with a unique id attribute to avoid conflicts between multiple modals.

Comment: I have tried it the way you just described by just using jQuery without the reference to the template but then I get "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function". I cannot figure out why this happens.

Comment: Strange, I've just knocked up some test code and it's working fine for me. Is there a <body> tag in any of your templates? Wondering if this is a similar issue to the one solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30381769/2723753

Comment: No I am using IronRouter and loading a layoutTemplate which has got the header and shows the content in the yield. I have got no body tag since Iron Router does this for me. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up from my comment, this is the code that is working for me. It definitely seems like you have an issue with jQuery finding multiple elements. I created a new meteor project:

```
$ meteor create semantic
$ cd semantic
$ meteor add semantic:ui-css
$ meteor add iron:router
```

**semantic.html**

```
<template name="MainLayout">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="projects">
    {{> xform}}
    <button class="newProject">New Project</button>
</template>

<template name="xform">
  <div id="modal" class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">New Project</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui form" id="newProject">
      <div class="one fields">
        <div class="field">
          <legend>Project Details</legend>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Project name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="button small createProject" style="color:white;position:relative;float:right;padding: 0.875rem 1.75rem 0.9375rem 1.75rem;font-size: 0.8125rem;" value="Create">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui button">
      Cancel
    </div>
    <div class="ui button">
      Okay
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**semantic.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.projects.events({
    'click .newProject': function(event, template){
      $('.ui.modal').modal({
            onDeny    : function(){
              return false;
            }}).modal('show');
    }
  });

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'MainLayout'
    })
    Router.route('/',{
      name: 'projects'
    })
  });
}
```

After running `meteor` and loading `http://localhost:3000` I can open and close the modal multiple times.

Comment: I have changed the jquery line to use $('#modal') and not the class which should prevent those things but it still does not work.

Comment: If I do a console.log($('#modal')) in my project and inside the code you used (which also works for me apparently) they both show the same but inside my project the problem still exists.

Comment: I still cannot find the error. I have got the same structure like you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the modal non-detachable in onRendered callback function of template.

```
Template.projects.onRendered(() => {
    $('.ui.modal').modal({ detachable: false });
});
```

Hope it helps.